# What might be preventing Unicode characters from displaying?

Tags: luatex, unicode

When I insert the [reference mark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203b/index.htm) character and compile the following MWE, the character shows up in the compiled output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

྿

\end{document}
```

But when I use the same character in my longer (memoir-based) document, it does not show up in the compiled PDF. There's just a blank space. However, the log shows no error; so, as a non-expert, it's tough for me to know where to start in debugging this.

#### Extra Details

In the character table for the font that I am, ideally, trying to get this to work with (Sabon Next), I can see the character, and it has the following notation:

```
UTF-8: 0xE2 0x80 0xBB
UTF-16: 0x203B
C octal escaped UTF-8: \342\200\273
XML decimal entity: &#8251;
```

The character is in the "General Punctuation" Unicode block. The same mark, with the same notation, in the same block, shows up in the character maps for Minion, Palatino, and other fonts. I have consulted the fontspec manual but have not found any guidance beyond the possibility that I may need to specify a distinct script to address this Unicode block (but, as far as I can see, there is no script for "General Punctuation" in the fontspec manual).

#### Possibly relevant portions of my preamble

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[draft,twoside,a5paper,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}
\setmainfont{Sabon Next LT Pro}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Sabon Next LT Pro}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Syntax LT Std}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}    
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\isopage
\checkandfixthelayout
```

What (probably very basic) thing am I missing here?

Comment: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/sabon-next/pro-regular/glyphs.html suggests that Sabon Next doesn’t have that glyph.

Comment: If you want to load a single symbol from a different font you have to use [`combofont`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/combofont) and LuaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions. Indeed it looks as though the glyph is not present in the font! This leaves me confused about what the character map is showing me, as it shows many more glyphs than seem to be in the font. But that's another question. Thanks again for the help.